# Understanding Pandas Pivot function

Tags: python, pandas

I want to convert a categorical column in a pandas dataframe to multiple columns containing values. Here is a minimal example dataframe

```
dfTest = pd.DataFrame({
    'animal' : ['cat','cat','dog','dog', 'mouse', 'mouse', 'rat', 'rat'],
    'color' : ['black', 'white', 'black', 'white', 'black', 'white', 'black', 'white'],
    'weight' : np.random.uniform(3, 20, 8)
})
dfTest
```

The table looks like this

[image]

According to [pandas user guide](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/reshaping.html), it seems to me that what I want to do is called a pivot. Namely, what I want to do should look something like this

```
  animal  weight_black  weight_white
0 cat     1.23456       2.34234
1 dog     3.634634      3.4554646
2 mouse   5.24234       5.463452
3 rat     4.56456       2.3364
```

However, when I run

```
dfTest.pivot(columns='color', values='weight')
```

I get the following:

[image]

I don't want other categorical columns (such as animal) to disappear. Also, I don't want nans inbetween, I want everything to be compact. How do I do this?

**EDIT**: Here's a more involved example of what I want

```
   animal  color  hair_length  weight
1  cat     black  long         1.23
2  cat     white  long         2.34
3  cat     black  short        34534
4  cat     white  short        345
5  dog     black  long         234
6  dog     white  long         123
7  dog     black  short        444
8  dog     white  short        345
9  rat     black  long         5465
10 rat     white  long         2343
11 rat     black  short        123
12 rat     white  short        2343
13 bat     black  long         423
14 bat     white  long         23
15 bat     black  short        11123
16 bat     white  short        13423
```

I want to convert it to

```
  animal  hair_length  weight_black  weight_white
1 cat     long         2.34          235
2 cat     short        345           3423 
3 dog     long         123           56346
4 dog     short        345           .... you get the point
5 rat     long         2343
6 rat     short        2343
7 bat     long         23
8 bat     short        13423
```

Comment: dfTest.pivot(columns='color', index='animal', values='weight')

Comment: Did you forget `index` argument in your `pivot`?

Comment: I don't want animal to be index. My actual dataframe has more columns. All other columns are categorical. Can I make it so that all other columns are preserved?

Comment: Then what do you want to have happen with the other columns? Do you just want to include all of them in the index?

Comment: Let me update the question

Comment: @Randy I updated, does this help?

Answer (score 0):

Ok I think I figured it out, @Randy's hint was actually enough

```
index = list(set(dfTest.columns) - {'color', 'weight'})
dfResult = df.pivot(index=index, columns='color', values='weight').reset_index()
```

So we

1. Put all of the columns except for the two columns of interest into index
2. Perform pivot, which results in complicated hierarchical index
3. Convert from complicated index to simple index by doing reset_index()

Comment: you can even add the method `.add_prefix('weight_')` between the `pivot` and the `reset_index`, you'll get the column name as you want

Comment: @Ben.T Thanks, that is useful